# IOS app adding a prefix to a call

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, prefix

I have started an iPhone app project that requires using the users address book and adding a prefix number to the beginning of a phone call.

What would be the best way to implement this? Is there a class already built for this type of function?

Answer (score 1):

[Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Once you have the number:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%i%@", prefix, retrievedNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

I haven't done it, but that should get you going.